# Card Layout getting an error

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

When the app launches it will display `screen1`. And then when we click on a button it will display `panel1` or `panel2`. My code as follows; I get an error when i add `panel2`.

```
launch: function() {


    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'card',
        items: [
        { 
            xtype: 'panel', 
        items: { xtype: 'screen1' }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            items: { xtype:'panel1' }
        }

        ] 
    }); 

}
```

As soon as i add another panel; and i get an error

```
TypeError: namespace is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (namespace === from || namespace.substring(0, from.length) === from) {
```

Code:

```
items: [
            { 
                xtype: 'panel', 
            items: { xtype: 'screen1' }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: { xtype:'panel1' }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: { xtype:'panel2' }
            }

        ]
```

NOTE: I have added the `Panel2` in the  `views: [ Panel2']`

**UPDATE**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Panel2', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.panel2',

    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    activeTab: 0,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Tab 1'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Tab 2'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Tab 3'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you share the contents of the file that defines your `panel2` `xtype`?

Comment: Can you also add the controller (or the complete app definition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because you're missing dependencies. Since you didn't post your application definition, you need to require the views in the controller (or, if you aren't even that far yet, in the requires on the application itself).

Have a look at /examples/app/simple in the download to see how it sets up requires.